# MS Word: how do I type an equation involving letters above/below an arrow?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

I am trying to reproduce the following in MS Word 2016. That is, letters above and below an arrow. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

[image: this]

Comment: Have you looked at the equation editor?

Comment: @fixer1234, yes I have but I did not find anything that worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type `->` in the equation editor. It will give you an arrow. Then type `\above`. Then when you press the space bar, the equation editor will give you the space to write on above the arrow. Similarly, when you type `\below` followed by a press on the space bar, you will find the slot to write under the arrow.

Comment: (+1) this also works with text other than arrows. For example, typing `x` followed by `\below`, and then pressing space, will result in a empty box below `x`, which you can put other symbols in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a direct solution, but there is a workaround with some drawbacks.

Insert empty matrix with 1 column and 2 rows. Then in the upper field insert one text and in the lower field insert arrow with placeholder for text below it. This workaround may involve putting some spaces around the text below arrow to make it longer. The drawback is that the arrow is not in the middle of the line and the text below the arrow is smaller than above.

The last drawback can be fixed by using 3x1 matrix and inserting arrow with only spaces as a text in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! That is a clever workaround. Perhaps I'll do it like this if it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

This question is fairly old, but for anyone looking for the actual solution, type (in word):`->\above(qwerty) \below(QWERTY)`

EDIT: su doesn't seem to display spaces correctly, so to clarify - you need a space before **and** after the whole string

Comment: Please provide more detail, where and how is the string place in the document?